# Detecting and ignoring mentioning of a named entity and extracting the valid named entity

Tags: nlp

I'm writing a java app that uses NLP for detecting named entities. I'm using the stanford university Named Entities code in my application. I've allready written a application to detect the names, compare them with a database. But I have a problem with the text itself.

I want to classify sentences in a text that have the mentioning of a name and ignore them.

Example:

> '....   This writer has the same writing style as Herman Melville.  .. '

The named entity is Herman Melville, but the text is not about Herman Melville, but other writers. Herman Melville is a true negative then.

Another example

> The Orb.
>
> Alex Paterson prides the Orb on manipulating obscure samples beyond recognition on its     albums and during its concerts; his unauthorised use of other artists’ works has led to     disputes with musicians, most notably with Rickie Lee Jones. During its live shows of the     1990s, the Orb performed using digital audio tape machines optimised for live mixing and     sampling before switching to laptops and digital media. Despite changes in performance     method, the Orb maintained its colourful light shows and psychedelic imagery in concert.     These visually intensive performances prompted critics to compare the group to Pink Floyd.

The artists that are detected are 'The Orb' and 'Pink Floyd'. The text is about The Orb, but the group is compared with Pink Floyd. So I want to use NLP to ignore 'Pink Floyd' and detect 'The Orb' as the Named Entity as the subject.

I allready have a database with example texts, where the writers are allready detected. I could use this as a test set. And I have a database with all the writers that exist.

I would like to have some examples or stuff to read on how to solve this problem. Even a discussion would be nice.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more. It seems like you want to ignore the sentences that contain any name but what is the problem you are facing is not clear.

Comment: I've added another example

Comment: Have a look at Stanford parser's collapsed dependency structure. You might use it for solving this problem. http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

Comment: I'm reading: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf. This looks like a good start!

Comment: Cool, but even with using dependency structure from stanford this problem is too broad. You might require to put in some constraints  and solve this for a subset of total possible sentence structures.

Comment: Could you give this as a reply, so I can give you some points?

Comment: Sorry completely lost track of this question. I will go through it again and add any constraints that I think can reduce the size of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, For your problem I would prefer to add a constraint like handling only the sentences that explicitly have an `name` in them. This would help you in reducing the set of sentences that go through your final processing. Because your requirement is the decide on what is the text actually about(removing true negative) I think looking for the `root` and `nsubj` clauses in the `grammatical dependency` structure generated by `Stanford parser` would put you in right direction. For your example `root` and `nsubj` clauses from the grammatical dependency structure looks something like

```
nsubj(performed-11, Orb-10)
root(ROOT-0, performed-11)

nn(Paterson-2, Alex-1)
nsubj(prides-3, Paterson-2)
root(ROOT-0, prides-3)

nsubj(maintained-9, Orb-8)
root(ROOT-0, maintained-9)

nsubj(prompted-5, performances-4)
root(ROOT-0, prompted-5)
```

Now from here you can check which of the names(Orb or Pink Floyd) exist in this structure maximum number of times. If Orb comes shows up more times then `Orb` is your output else if `Pink Floyd` does then that is your final output. But you have to take into consideration the the name (`orb` is one word while `pink floyd` is two words for which you can take into consideration `nn` clause)and that would be you final output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added some more information in my answer. Please go through it again.